# Display the content of a table which is appended in stringbuilder, in a asp.net page using any control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I appended the result of a select query to a table which is appended in stringbuilder. i can see the result by using the  Response.write()  code. but i want to display the content in a specific place of my page .how to do this?

Comment: question is not clear, what are the contents of stringbuilder object before appending the query result, what are the new contents ? If you can put something in Response.Write() successfully, then you should be able to display it in a text box or label etc, if you want it to be displayed in rows and columns, then you must write separate logic for it, in any case some code would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

1. Take a div tag on page with runat="server" and id="dvoutput"
2. Then in code :-

> dvoutput.InnerHtml = yourstringbuilderobject.ToString();

Comment: sure, but i have only 11 reputation. i need to get 15 then only i am eligible to vote